# iText PDF - After merging two pdfs with PdfCopy, PDFActions (PdfAction.gotoLocalPage) are lost/does't work

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I created PDF documents file1.pdf and file2.pdf (almost similar files with different data). Each file has **its own Table of Contents** with PdfAction which on clicking an element in the table of contents navigate to the respective pages in the respective documents. It works properly.

I used the below code to set actions on TOC elements

```
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Analysis Report");
chunk.setAction(PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(title, true));
```

---

**THE PROBLEM IS ...**

On merging these two documents, using PDFCopy the actions I have set in the source PDFs are lost in the new merged PDF.

Below is the code I use to merge the two PDF documents.

---

```
File file1 = new File("file1.pdf");
PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(file1.getAbsolutePath());

File file2 = new File("file2.pdf");
PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(file2.getAbsolutePath());

File tempDestFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".pdf");
Document document = TemplateHelper.getDocument(PageSize.A4);
PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(tempDestFile.getAbsolutePath()));

document.open();

copy.addDocument(reader1);
copy.addDocument(reader2);

document.close();
copy.close();
reader1.close();
```

---

Comment: I don't know how PdfSmartCopy deals with TOC. Did you try to use PdfCopy? If it does not work you might need to manually copy the TOC over to the new document...

Answer (score 0):

You can merge two PDF's using Apache PDF.

below is the sample code snippet.

```
    PDFMergerUtility ut = new PDFMergerUtility();
    ut.addSource(file1);
    ut.addSource(file2);
    ut.setDestinationFileName("done.pdf");
    ut.mergeDocuments();
```

Use below dependency for Apache PDF box.

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
<artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
<version>2.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: PDFBox is not iText. The question, though, is focused on iText.

Comment: Yup @mkl , i have tried to merge two PDF's in itext  its not working, but we can do it in PDFBox.